# tinyMCE 4 Pop-Up Tools Lose Focus in Colorbox Lightbox

Tags: tinymce, colorbox

I'm trying to move my website to tinyMCE 4, but I've run across a few stumbling blocks since version 4 is still in beta and the documentation on http://www.tinymce.com/ is pretty sparse at this point. I've been able to solve most of my issues, but this onea has me stumped and I'm not even sure how to determine where things are going wrong.

I set up a test site at http://ymsrunning.com/mce.php. You'll notice that using any of the toolbar buttons on the main page works fine. You can type in the input boxes and they start with focus.

The problem is when you click on the link to bring up a Colorbox, those same tools do not work. Even though the pop-up window will appear, the inputs do not have focus and you cannot click on them to input anything.

tinyMCE creates their own input box to match the theme, but I can't figure out what they do to the focus. Any thoughts on how I should proceed or, even better, what the problem is, would be much appreciated.

Comment: wait for tinymce4 to get out of beta - saves some headache

Comment: Fair suggestion. I'm sure this isn't something they will overlook since Colorbox is a pretty popular lightbox, but I'd like to solve it myself (or with the help of someone here) if I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out this wasn't an issue with tinyMCE, it was an issue with Colorbox. Colorbox prevents focus on anything outside of its container and tinyMCE creates its elements outside the Colorbox container. There is a function in the Colorbox code called "trapFocus" that creates this behavior. The code is below.

```
function trapFocus(e) {
if ('contains' in $box[0] && !$box[0].contains(e.target)) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $box.focus();
    }
}
```

Commenting out the content inside the function, but not the function itself lets elements retain and accept focus and prevents Colorbox from messing with it. I hope this helps anyone else who runs into this issue.

Comment: Oh boy!! Genius!! That probably saved me days of headaches!! Thank you for this great finding!! I'll give the developer of colorbox a headsup :-)

Comment: Actually, by removing the whole function, I get some weird click-through causing the browser to scroll down on opening colorbox. However, it works all (currently) when ONLY removing "$box.focus();" from the trapFocus function of colorbox.

Comment: That's why I said remove the "contents" of the function, but it seems removing the "$box.focus();" line works as well.

Comment: I did remove the content, but the function does make sense for colorbox, too ... so removing its functionality isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: *lol* As it turns out, this function is quite new to colorbox and it can easily be turned off by setting "trapFocus: false" when calling colorbox :-) And so, no patching is needed :) https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/commit/b357a79ff44d21b60b5ce42fcedfd85b01a5de64